# How do I solve this system of differential equations? $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-y}{x}+x z, \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{-2y}{x^3}+\frac{z}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this system of differential equations? 
$$\left\{\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-y}{x}+x z,\\ \frac{dz}{dx}&=\frac{-2y}{x^3}+\frac{z}{x}\end{align}\right.$$
So, I have quite no idea about this one.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can eliminate the variable $z$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uusually when you solve a system of differential equations, you follow a similar approach of solving an algebraic system, i.e. you express a variable in function of the others and then you substitute with it into the remaining equations.

In your case  you can differentiate the first equation with respect to $x$ to get

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dz}{dx} + z $$

Now you can substitute with the second equation to get

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx} + x \left[-\frac{2y}{x^3} + \frac{z}{x} \right]+ z $$

Now you can substitute for $z$ from the first equation to finally get

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx} -\frac{2y}{x^2} + 2 \left[ \frac{1}{x} \frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x^2} \right] $$

Simplification yields

$$ x^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} - x \frac{d y}{dx} -y = 0 $$

The solution is

$$y(x)=C_0 x^{1+\sqrt{2}}+C_1 x^{1-\sqrt{2}}$$

$C_0$ and $C_1$ are constants to be determined from the boundary conditions. Now you can easily calculate $z(x)$.